# read array name from STDIN and iterating through the array values

Tags: arrays, shell

I have number of arrays but want to iterate only through one entered through STDIN
My code looks like

```
ARR1=(a b c)
ARR2=(d e f)
ARR3=(g h i)

read array_name

for i in ${array_name[@]}
do
echo "i is $i"
done
```

Now if I enter ARR1 as input, ARR1 values are not printing. Can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
ARR1=(a b c)
ARR2=(d e f)
ARR3=(g h i)

read array_name

array_name="${array_name}[@]"    # append '[@]' to array_name

for i in "${!array_name}" ; do   # use indirection to expand e.g. "${ARR1[@]}"
    echo "i is $i"
done
```